# Add different value types to mysql tables' columns

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Is there any way to add different types of values in the SAME column in a MySQL table?

EDIT: Every row has a varchar data field in a column that has a numerical value associated to it in another field in another column. Is it possible to save these numbers as float type in some rows and int in some others?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you would like to happen? A before and after of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes 3 columns:

```
(Int)     (Int)      (Float)
IsInt     IntVal     FloatVal
1         14         NULL
1         2011       NULL
0         NULL       23.33
0         NULL       2.5
1         13         NULL
1         42         NULL
```

Then you can check the IsInt field to see which data type you used.

Answer (score 0):

If by types, you mean data with values represented by something other than what the column has for its specified datatype, as in ints in blob fields or some such, then no.

Data could be turned into a serialized format such as JSON or XML and saved in a text field, but this isn't advisable for most applications for a whole host of reasons, and a key value store like MongoDB or Redis would probably much better approximate this behavior if that's what's desired.

One wonders why you would want to do this?  Can you specify what you'd be looking to accomplish by this and perhaps we can find a better method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about MySQL support for objects, but it could be a solution.
Anyway, if you need manage only one information, but you don't need type, you can store it as "string" and do a really good job on code to parse it.